# Provide Datetime formatting while BCP export

Tags: bcp

BCP export outputs dates in yyyy-mm-dd format, I need them to be in yyyy.mm.dd format. The export file is consumed by another application which is rigid.
I am going to do bcp export for large number of tables and it would be great if I can apply this formatting to all date columns in a result set without explicitly specifying the date columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONVERT` to get the desired format and then `REPLACE` to have '.' instead of '-':

```
BCP "SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126),'-','.')" QUERYOUT "d:\out.txt" -c -T
```

This is the content of the output file:

> 2018.03.02